# Shortest way to restore SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, ssms

I have to restore various SQL server databases several times a day (for development purposes). In SSMS interface it takes forever and it is even longer to type RESTORE DATABASE command with all it's paths. 
Ideally I would like to double-click a BAK file right in Windows Explorer and run something to restore it.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: I wrote a powershell, well  technically 2. one server-side dumps the production databases to a specificed directory and then 7zips them. Client downloads using a webclient from powershell unzips, and restores and then uses sproc to realign username etc.. Can share if interested, will need to adapt to your scenario but works for me

Answer (score 2):

> In SSMS interface it takes forever and it is even longer to type RESTORE DATABASE command with all it's paths.

Use the wizard that is built in, right click database-->tasks-->restore database

from there you can navigate to the backup file if you select `from device` as the source

then before you restore, hit the script button on the top left and save this script, in the future all you have to change is the file name then

Another option is detach and attach. detach log and data files at the source, copy the files over and attach the files

See here [Detaching and Attaching Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190794.aspx)